# Accessing a property that is also an Array {React, Javascript} returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This might looks stupid, but i'm lost. I want to Map through countries and regions array. I have a `Countries Array` that also includes `Region's Array`. I can access the Countries Array, but when i try to access the `Regions Array` i returned from the `Countries Array`, it returns undefined. Here is a minimal example.

Full code on [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-brook-j4cvr?file=/src/App.js)

```js
const Countries = [
  {
    countryName: "Afghanistan",
    countryShortCode: "AF",
    regions: [
      {
        name: "Badakhshan",
        shortCode: "BDS",
      },
      {
        name: "Badghis",
        shortCode: "BDG",
      },
      {
        name: "Helmand",
        shortCode: "HEL",
      },
      {
        name: "Herat",
        shortCode: "HER",
      },
      {
        name: "Jowzjan",
        shortCode: "JOW",
      },
      {
        name: "Kabul",
        shortCode: "KAB",
      },
      {
        name: "Kandahar",
        shortCode: "KAN",
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    countryName: "Åland Islands",
    countryShortCode: "AX",
    regions: [
      {
        name: "Brändö",
        shortCode: "BR",
      },
      {
        name: "Eckerö",
        shortCode: "EC",
      },
      {
        name: "Sund",
        shortCode: "SD",
      },
      {
        name: "Vårdö",
        shortCode: "VR",
      },
    ],
  }
]

const mappedCountries = Countries.map(({ regions }) => regions);
const mappedRegion = mappedCountries.map(({ name }) => name);

console.log(mappedCountries);
console.log(mappedRegion);
```

Comment: ok, it seams to be easy, but can you show us the arrays please

Comment: ah sorry i didnt see the CodeSandBox, sorry

Comment: `mappedCountries` is an array of arrays of objects, so you need to iterate deeper.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @pilchard please avoid adding code found on external sites to SO even if the OP linked to it. You [might be](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344484/pasting-fiddle-snippet-into-original-question-as-an-edit/344512#344512) in [breach of license](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348698/edits-that-add-ops-code-from-3rd-party-site-where-the-license-is-unavailable). It's better to allow OP to make that change. See also [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are returing an array in the map method. so the result is an array of arrays.

you need to `flatten` your result. an easy alternative would be using `reduce`

```
const mappedCountries = Countries.reduce((memo, { regions }) => [...memo, ...regions], []);
const mappedRegion = mappedCountries.map(({ name }) => name);
```

Comment: You nailed it!... Thanks Man!

Comment: You can change your condition inside map like this -

Answer (score 1):

You can change your condition inside second map like this to access region's name -
`mappedCountries.map(e => e.map(({name}) => name))`

Comment: but this will also return an array of arrays, and not just one single array with names in it.